# Accessing a local SQL Server 2008 database with pyodbc on Windows 7

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect to a local copy of a SQL Server 2008 database (it connects to the remote production database just fine).

However, when I try connecting to the local copy using the following command:

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL
Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=me;PWD=pw')
```

the connection fails with the following error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17)
(SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (5)')
```

Trying to connect via Windows authentication (with `'Trusted_Connection=yes'`) fails as well.

I can connect to the local database fine using SQL Server Management Studio with both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication. Any ideas why I can't connect with pyodbc?

Comment: What version of MDAC? Guessing it's an older version due to the `{SQL Server}` provider. Older versions had some trouble with named pipes and the use of `localhost` as server name. Have you tried newer version of the [native client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)?

Comment: Have you tried server = (local)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling SQL Server did the trick