# Pyodbc can't find FreeTDS driver

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, centos7, freetds

I am on a Centos 7 Linux machine trying to connect to an SQL database through pyodbc. I learned that you need to setup the DSN and you do that by installing the freetds driver and doing something like:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=example;DATABASE=TEST;')
```

Unfortunately when I do that I get an error saying the driver FreeTDS can't be found. I have ran:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

It seemed to have installed it but I get the same error. Can someone please send me a link to a working example

Comment: It's help for me [try this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041298/12790377)

Answer (score 7):

To build on [@FlipperPA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33160142/648162), it's not obvious how pyodbc "finds" the FreeTDS driver. If you have this error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

There can be other possible causes, including an incorrect environment. Here's what I discovered:

pyodbc is a wrapper around unixODBC, which isn't documented, but you need to [install the `unixODBC` devel packages](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install) before you can `pip install pyodbc`. pyodbc passes the connection string directly to unixODBC.

unixODBC needs to load a shared library containing the ODBC database driver, for example `libtdsodbc.so` for FreeTDS. You can set the `DRIVER` parameter in the connect string to one of two things:

- Either the direct path to the shared library file (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so`)
- Or the name of a config section in `odbcinst.ini`, which contains a `Driver = ...` setting that points to the shared library file

The first way is guaranteed to find the shared library, and a good way to check whether you have environment issues, but the second way is preferred and more portable. See [here](http://www.unixodbc.org/internals.html) for more details:

> This ini file simply lists all installed drivers. It is located in
>   /etc/odbcinst.ini. The syntax is simple; a name followed by a property
>   which tells us the drivers file name. For example;
>
> ```
> [Sybase 11] 
> Comment = Super Duper Sybase Server 
> Driver =  /usr/lib/libsybase.so.11 
> Setup = /usr/lib/libsybaseS.so.11 
> FileUsage = 1
> ```
>
> The Driver file name (ie `/usr/lib/libsybase.so.11`) should be unique.
>   The friendly name (ie `Sybase 11`) must also be unique.

However, this can only work if unixODBC can find your `odbcinst.ini` file. It appears to search for it:

- [in your home directory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.common.usage.doc/topics/t_configuring_nzodbcdriver.html) with a modified name, `.odbcinst.ini`
- In the directory pointed to by the `ODBCSYSINI` environment variable, if set.
- Otherwise, in `/etc`.

For FreeTDS it should contain something like this:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = For example, my database server name or FreeTDS version
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Only then can you use `DRIVER=FreeTDS` in a connect string and expect it to work (and not get the above error).

You might also want to use the `ldd` command (on Linux) to check that all of the library's dependencies are satisfied, and can be found and loaded by the dynamic library loader, `ld.so`:

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so'
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe145fe000)
        libodbcinst.so.2 => /lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f81f9dfd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f81f9bf8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f81f99dc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f81f961b000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f81f940f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f81fa2ac000)
```

If you are still stuck, you might want to start over from scratch by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36985668/648162) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239553/648162) answer.

Comment: Where is libtdsodbc.so in Alpine?

Answer (score 6):

If you're compiling FreeTDS from source, it'll install to /usr/local/freetds, IIRC. You can also install via `yum` on CentOS, and you'll need unixODBC as well. Basically, FreeTDS bridges SQL Server to unixODBC, and pyodbc bridges unixODBC to Python.

Here's an example set up with FreeTDS, unixODBC, and friends:

freetds.conf:

```
[server]
        host = server.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.3
```

odbc.ini:

```
[server]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = server.com
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.3
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS with Protocol up to 7.3
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
```

The `Driver =` location may differ above, depending on your distro of FreeTDS - if you compiled from source, most likely, `/usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so`.

pyodbc connect, DSN free:

```
DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=server.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=dbuser;PWD=dbpassword;TDS_Version=7.3;
```

A few notes:

- You'll have to update the TDS version to match the version of SQL Server you are running and the Free TDS version you are running. Version 0.95 supports TDS Version 7.3.
- TDS Version 7.3 will work with MS SQL Server 2008 and above.
- Use TDS Version 7.2 for MS SQL Server 2005.

See here for more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339982.aspx

Good luck.