# How can i make SQLAlchemy engine and upload the DataFrame from within Airflow Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, airflow, pyodbc

essentially I use [puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) Docker image modified for using pyodbc and cx_oracle drivers and PythonVirtualenvOperator, but when I try to create sqlalchemy engine

```
db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SK-BI-02/DWH?driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.1.1&domain=domain&password={}&login=user&port=1433'.format(_pass))
target_frame.to_sql('some_path',db_engine,'scheme',index=False,if_exists='append')
```

it continues to give such traceback

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

how to make it works or maybe there is another way to upload DataFrame from airflow in a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of suffering the only thing that is worked for me is the usage of FreeTDS driver instead of Microsft ODBC one, following answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695990/authenticate-from-linux-to-windows-sql-server-with-pyodbc).
Not sure but I guess it somehow related to Microsoft Auth of MSSQL and its security configuration...