# Trouble with access to i Series AS400 database via pyodbc and Linux (using Docker)

Tags: python, linux, odbc, kerberos, ibm-midrange

I'm testing an API using Fast API and Docker. When I load up the webpage it attempts to run a query using an AS400 connection that is setup with pyodbc.

I started with the error: `pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8051 - CWBSY1011 - Kerberos client credentials not found`

So I installed krb5 and created a ticket. Then re-loaded the webpage and the new error I am stuck at is `pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8052 - CWBSY1012 - Kerberos service principal not found for system SYSTEM` where SYSTEM is my AS400 system's name.

Has anyone else run into this before? It seems like AS400 is requiring me to use Kerberos on connecting but then I set it up and the system does not have a Kerberos service principal.

Do I possibly need to join the domain fully using the [instructions found here](https://wiki.debian.org/AuthenticatingLinuxWithActiveDirectory)? I started this process however I run into an error: `Failed to join domain: Not enough storage is available to process this command.` when trying to run `net ads join` which I am assuming is due to the Docker image being so small; so I assume this is not possible.

Here is my ODBC.ini config file:

```
[QDSN_ASW]
Description=ASW
Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System=192.168.100.1
UserID=user
Password=pass
Naming=0
DefaultLibraries=QGPL
Database=1492BFDD
ConnectionType=2
CommitMode=2
ExtendedDynamic=0
DefaultPkgLibrary=QGPL
DefaultPackage=A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression=1
LibraryView=0
AllowUnsupportedChar=0
ForceTranslation=0
Trace=0
Trusted_Connection=no
AuthenticationType=No Authentication
```

Comment: Never messed with IBM360 / AS400 / iSeries _but_ I don't think you need to "join" an Active Directory domain -- Kerberos auth to a non-Microsoft system does not require all the Microsoft bloatware and "features". You will need a proper Kerberos client conf in `/etc/krb5.conf` instead. Especially if your user principal (UPN) is not in the same _realm_ as the service principal (SPN).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue thanks to [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138369/10134961).

Basically, it appears my original construction of the database connection (shown below) was too convoluted and unnecessary.

```
 class CommitMode:
     NONE = 0  # Commit immediate (*NONE)  --> QSQCLIPKGN
     CS = 1  # Read committed (*CS)        --> QSQCLIPKGS
     CHG = 2  # Read uncommitted (*CHG)    --> QSQCLIPKGC
     ALL = 3  # Repeatable read (*ALL)     --> QSQCLIPKGA
     RR = 4  # Serializable (*RR)          --> QSQCLIPKGL


 class ConnectionType:
     ReadWrite = 0  # Read/Write (all SQL statements allowed)
     ReadCall = 1  # Read/Call (SELECT and CALL statements allowed)
     Readonly = 2  # Read-only (SELECT statements only)


 def connstr(system, commitmode=None, connectiontype=ConnectionType.Readonly):
     _connstr =  'DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;'+ \
                 'SYSTEM='+system+';'+\
                 'SIGNON=4;CCSID=1208;TRANSLATE=1;'
     if commitmode is not None:
         _connstr = _connstr + 'CommitMode=' + str(commitmode) + ';'
     if connectiontype is not None:
         _connstr = _connstr +'ConnectionType=' + str(connectiontype) + ';'

     return _connstr
```

and I was able to simplify it to:

```
system = f"SYSTEM=AS400;DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;SERVER=192.168.100.0;PORT=446;DATABASE=AS400;UID={user};PWD={pw}"
```

Now when I build the Docker image and load the web page, it instantly queries the database with no Kerberos authentication required.