# Django adds square Brackets in querying sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc, freetds

I am trying to connect to azure sql service from my django on mac osx. 
When I do following

```
from photo_mapper.models import Restaurant
rest_query = Restaurant.objects.all().query
print rest_query
SELECT [ate_it.restaurant].[id], [ate_it.restaurant].[name], [ate_it.restaurant].[area], [ate_it.restaurant].[city], [ate_it.restaurant].[submitter], [ate_it.restaurant].[pending], [ate_it.restaurant].[zid] FROM [ate_it.restaurant]
```

Due to which when I do `Restaurant.objects.all()` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 234, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/anubhav/workspace/ate-it/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 538, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ate_it.restaurant'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

However when I manually run the query `SELECT * from ate_it.restaurant` using `django.db.connections` it runs fine. 
Can I prevent django from adding the square brackets.

My database settings are

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER' : 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD' : 'mypwd',
        'HOST' : 'myserver',
        'PORT' : '1433',
    }
}
```

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678696/sql-server-python-and-os-x) for freetds and unixodbc setup

Comment: What packages and version are you using for Python and Django? There are a few; I'm guessing pyodbc==3.0.10, but which Django package? Is `ate_it.restaurant` a schema + table name combination?

Comment: I am using Django 1.9.7. ate_it is the schema and restaurant is the table name

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the pyodbc. It generates the quoted name of table, index or column. 
Modify this function quote_name in pyodbc/operations.py
Change this line 
`return '[%s]' % name` to  `return name`