# SQL Server, Python, on Mac OS

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, unixodbc

First of all, I know this question was asked/answered once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678696/sql-server-python-and-os-x), but I followed the steps suggested here, and got stucked in the middle of the steps.

Before the question, I have a Python script which runs well on a CentOS server:

```py
import pyodbc 

server = 'tcp:192.168.1.1' 
database = 'MYDB' 
username = 'username' 
password = 'password'

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DB1;"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
```

The same script gives me error on macOS, so I followed the nstruction in the previous [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678696/sql-server-python-and-os-x) step by step, I had **FreeTDS** installed, and tested with `tsql -S 192.168.1.1 -U username -P password`. Things were fine so far.

Then I installed **unixODBC** with `brew install unixodbc`, and did the configuration as suggested:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini

[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL on Win32
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

and..

```
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini

[MYSERVER]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/sql.log
Database            = 'MYDB'
Servername          = 'tcp:192.168.1.1'
UserName            = 'username'
Password            = 'password'
Port                = 1433
Protocol            = 8.0
ReadOnly            = No
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
```

Then I tested..

```
$ isql -v MYSERVER
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[08S01][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
[01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

also..

```
$ isql -v tcp:192.168.1.1 username password
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Back to my python script on macOS, I changed a little bit, and still could not connect to SQL server..

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue? Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you follow the next steps, should be work with Mac M2, Ventura +

1. `brew install unixodbc`
2. `pip uninstall pyodbc`
3. `pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc`
4. install drivers for 18  (copy and paste bash code), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15
5. run python code and get connected

```
  import pyodbc 
  server = 'xxxxx.database.windows.net' 
  database = 'xxx' 
  username = 'xxx@xx.x.com' 
  password = 'xxxxx' 
  cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password )
  cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

if you have different settings, like Active Directory User, make sure you add at the end of the connection string

`Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;Encrypt=yes;`

Check more settings here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16